# Extracting a list of ints, from a list of mixed strings

Tags: python, python-3.7, appium-android

So I'm automating with appium looking at some cards with price results.  My goal is to make a list, shave off the alpha chars and the `$` and `/`, Followed by turning that list into ints. Then assert my ints are < #

I'm new to python and coding in general. Moreover have little resources at work other then the internet, Thanks for any help in advance.

I've tried a few things I've been able to get the best result with

```
my_list.strip(str(["$","/day"]))
```

Weirdly its returning a var = string of only the second list item with everything successfully cut off except my number.

````
```this list is actually being made in a custom function
price_check = ['$7/day', '$1/day', '$3/day', '$1/day']

```This is what I've got the best result with
for price_ints in price_check:
    price_check.strip(str(["$","/day"]))
````

`print(price_ints)` printed `1` which is cool. However I lost the rest of my list.

Other things I've tried

1. `price_check = [re.sub('$/aday', '', item) for item in price_check]`
2. `mylst = map(lambda each:each.strip("/aday"), price_check)` printed `<map object at 0x0000025276184898>`
3. `price_ints = [s for s in price_check if s.isdigit()]`

I'd love to expect my output to be a list of strings of numbers that I can convert to int's

`['7', '1', '3', '1']`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're almost there, but you should append the new result to a new list. Also you need to strip the result from `price_ints` instead of `price_check`. You could do the following;

```
price_check = ['$7/day', '$1/day', '$3/day', '$1/day']
prices = []

for price_ints in price_check:
    prices.append(price_ints.strip("$/day"))

print(prices)
```

Output:

```
['7', '1', '3', '1']
```

You can also achieve the same with list comprehension:

```
prices = [price_int.strip("$/day") for price_int in price_check]
```

A note on your own attempt at list comprehension, it's close but you're checking if the whole string `isdigit()`, what you could do is a second loop, which will loop over each individual letter in the string:

```
price_ints = [letter for string in price_check for letter in string if letter.isdigit()]
```

Comment: Dude those worked like a charm thanks! I was goin crazy, I knew I was close but couldn't wrap my head around ^.^